# Import from parent directory in Flutter

Tags: import, flutter

I want to make a couple of complicated widgets in their own files in another folder, which will be imported and configured by a helper script. Here is the file tree:

```
- lib/
  - constants.dart
  - file1.dart
  - file2.dart
  - main.dart
  - utils.dart
  - utils/
    - complex_widget1.dart
    - complex_widget2.dart
    - complex_widget3.dart
```

Here is what is in `utils.dart`

```
import "utils/complex_widget1.dart";
import "utils/complex_widget2.dart";
import "utils/complex_widget3.dart";

class Utils {
    final Widget1 widget1;
    final Widget2 widget2;
    final Widget3 widget3;
    final String data_needed_by_widgets;
    Utils (this.data_needed_by_widgets) : 
        widget1 = Widget1(data_needed_by_widgets),
        widget2 = Widget2(data_needed_by_widgets),
        widget3 = Widget3(data_needed_by_widgets);
}
```

This should work fine. But the problem comes when I want to access `constants.dart` in my widgets (It holds a bunch of `const` Strings and other stuff that I use across all my files):

`utils/complex_widget1.dart`:

```
// Pretend this has actually complicated stuff
import "constants.dart";  // How do I import this?
class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build (BuildContext context) => Center (
        child: Text (TITLE_TEXT)  // From constants.dart
    );
}
```

I can't just import the individual variables from `constants.dart`, they're all global and there are no classes or functions to pass as arguments. How do I access values from `constants.dart` from `Widget1` (or any other `complex_widget`, for that matter)?

Comment: `import '../constants.dart';`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You *can* use relative paths

```
import '../../constants.dart';
```

But you *should* use package paths so moving the files doesn't require editing the imports.

```
import 'package:YOUR_PACKAGE/constants.dart';
```

Note the `lib/` directory is omitted in `package` paths.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been Googling for HOURS!

Comment: By the way, the second pair of "." only has one, not two. Thanks so much though!

Comment: I've been looking through to find a way to export some files in my test package and for some reason I thought that a relative path is '...' (three dots) instead of '..' (two dots). Thanks!

Comment: How can I Import a file ?

Comment: Is the package set by default? How do I know my app's package name?

Comment: Nevermind, just found it: my apps package name is the app's name